# Python3: If and else are running fine but when I add elif there is no output

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a simple if, elif and else statements. 
My code is:

```
def main():
    x, y = 100, 100


    if (x < y):
        st = "x is less than y"
    elif (x == y):
        st = "x is the same as y"
    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    print(st)
```

I started with just `if` and `else`, and I got `"x is greater than y"`. Obviously, it's not correct so I added an `elif` statement to get "x is the same as y". However, when I run the above code, there is no output. It doesn't come up with error, just blank.

Can someone explain to me why is it so or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you pls show the indentation exactly as in your code. It matters!

Comment: you should call main function and follow dents in if statments

Comment: @schwobaseggl The code was clearly pasted as is. Just adding surround `\`\`\`` "fixed" the indentation.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, can you clarify things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

the function `main` should call after all

```
def main():
    x, y = 100, 100


    if (x < y):
        st = "x is less than y"
    elif (x == y):
        st = "x is the same as y"
    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    print(st)

main()
```

Comment: This hasn't helped, I'm still getting no output.

Comment: @Dan Zastavnyuk I tried it on my SDK it works, please share the error you have
Also tell me where you try it(you run python on command windows?)

Comment: I get no error message. I've just started learning so apologies if my explanation is off or incorrectly phrased. I'm getting used to the programming language. I type my code in Visual Studio Code and start debugging. I also opened the file on command windows.

Comment: you don't have issue when it is bigger or smaller value? just if it is equal?
did you copy and past this in VS code?

Comment: Same issue if x is smaller. But when x is smaller it doesn't work for both cases (i.e. with or without elif)

Comment: I didn't copy the code, I made modifications to mine. I've just copied your code and it worked. Apologies for confusing you. Imma try to figure out why my code doesn't work and yours does. Thank you so much

Comment: You should follow space or dent in if , only issue that may cause this,lets spaces made by VS code

Answer (score 0):

You need to run main after the you define it.
Unlike other programming languages, Python doesn't
automatically run a function called `main`.

```
def main():
  # your code

main()
```

Comment: This hasn't helped. I'm still getting no output

Comment: Then try removing the parentheses from the if statement. If that fails I can't help you.

Comment: It's still the same. Thank you for you help tho!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with elif. a function needs an output and something must be returned. plus you have to call the function somewhere so it works.
so you could try this:

```
def main():
    x, y = 100, 100
    if x < y:
        st = "x is less than y"
    elif x == y:
        st = "x is equal to y"
    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    return st


print(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok, You just forgot to call the function main().